# Saber resultado de count() em query

Tags: sql, pdo, query

Tenho a seguinte query em pdo:

```
$ranking = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios GROUP BY moedas ORDER BY count(moedas) DESC LIMIT 3");
```

Uso isso para fazer um ranking para saber os usuários com mais moedas. Porém, estou utilizando uma segunda query com rowCount() para saber a quantidade de moedas do usuário listado, seria possível extrair o valor do count(moedas) dessa primeira query (citada no post)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Veja o exemplo:

```
 $results= "
 SELECT p1.*, aa.moedas AS numbers
 FROM usuarios aa
 ORDER BY aa.moedas * 1 DESC
 DESC LIMIT 3
 ";

$stmt = $pdocon->prepare($results);
$stmt->execute();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
echo $row["numbers"];
}
```

Comment: Não é isso que quero amigo, preciso saber o valor do COUNT(moedas).

Comment: Editei a resposta. Você tem que explicar melhor a estrutura da sua tabela.

Comment: E como faço pra exibir?

Comment: Editei novamente a minha resposta.